# long underscore before the number in enumerate environment

Tags: underscore

I am making a simple exam using the code below:

```
\begin {document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\end{enumerate}
\end {document}
```

I want to put a long underscore before each number where students can put their answer like this:

______________ 1. Text here

______________ 2. Text here

______________ 3. Text here

______________ 4. Text here

______________ 5. Text here

______________ 6. Text here

______________ 7. Text here

______________ 8. Text here

______________ 9. Text here

_____________ 10. Text here

_____________ 11. Text here

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to load the `enumerate` package and set the labels as you want. That long underline may be achieved using a `\rule{2cm}{.4pt}`, for example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{\rule{2cm}{.4pt} 1.}]
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another option which takes into account the width of the numbers greater than 9:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill~~\arabic*.}},leftmargin=*]
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item Text here
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I am using miktex and texmaker sir.

Comment: I am using the code \ begin{enumerate}[label=rule {1.5in}{0.15mm}~\arabic*, align=left, leftmargin=*]

Comment: Yes, that should work with any LaTeX engine or editor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I just change the \begin {enumitem} in the preamble to \begin {enumerate}.

Comment: Another problem sir. The text are aligned properly but the line before the number is not aligned after number 9

Comment: @KenMirasol  -- Please see my second option addressing this problem

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I already use the second option and it resolves my problems. But there's no dot after the number sir.

Comment: Last concern sir. I want to align the dots after the number too as well as the text.

Comment: Sir the line in number 10 is closer to the number. Can we adjust it to the left the same distance with numbers 1 to 9

Comment: Sir  see my edited post. I want my quiz to look like that

Comment: OK, I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: When were you knighted?!

Comment: @KenMirasol If this answer solved your problem, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy using `enumitem` tools. The `[wide=0pt]` option sets the document margin as the list margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[1in][r]{\hrulefill~\arabic*.}}, wide=0pt, ref=\arabic*, start=7]
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item  A longer text here. A longer text. A longer text. A longer text. A longer text. A longer text. A longer text. 
\item Text here
\item Text here
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr: As long as the answer  are one-lined, none. For longer answers, the left margin of the list is the left margin of the body, thanks to the  `wide=0pt` option. I've modified the text to show this.